# How to see which accounts contain unread e-mails when they are not expanded?

Tags: thunderbird

In earlier versions of Thunderbird you knew which account folders had incoming e-mails even when they are not expanded. Usually the mailbox icon left beside the e-mail-address account changed and showed a little green arrow.
Now this is totally stupid, the icons doesn't change when there are any incoming e-mails. You get a notification, but I even want to see which mailbox have incoming e-mails. Otherwise I need to expand all my e-mail accounts and I don't have so much space on view.

I already tried another theme, but same result. I already tried to disable the default extensions but it didn't help. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it's really a theme issue. Obviously many themes suck and don't display that, but I found a theme which does.